# Springboot2 use StringRedisTemplate can't connect to redis cluster in docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, redis, docker-swarm

I set up the redis-cluster in docker in aws ec2. They use the docker swarm net. The ip is from 10.0.0.6:6379 to 10.0.0.11:6379 and is mapped to the ec2 static address like (public address:5001 to public address:5006) I can use the client tool like TablePlus to access them using public address successfully. But when I use the spring boot(version 2.1.1) and StringRedisTemplate to set value in redis,(the configuration file is

```
spring.redis.database=0
spring.redis.password=xxxxxx
spring.redis.cluster.nodes=public address:5001,public address:5002,public address:5003,public address:5004,public address:5005,public address:5006
spring.redis.timeout=5000
```

The pom is

```
    <!-- redis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

, I always got the error message like below:

```
2019-01-14 08:15:28,570 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] [org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:524)] - [INFO] Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-01-14 08:15:28,577 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] [org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:546)] - [INFO] Completed initialization in 7 ms
2019-01-14 08:15:52,589 [http-nio-8081-exec-8] [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:110)] - [INFO] HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-01-14 08:15:56,831 [http-nio-8081-exec-8] [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:123)] - [INFO] HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2019-01-14 08:15:58,734 [http-nio-8081-exec-8] [io.lettuce.core.EpollProvider.<clinit>(EpollProvider.java:68)] - [INFO] Starting without optional epoll library
2019-01-14 08:15:58,736 [http-nio-8081-exec-8] [io.lettuce.core.KqueueProvider.<clinit>(KqueueProvider.java:70)] - [INFO] Starting without optional kqueue library
2019-01-14 08:16:09,935 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-1] [io.lettuce.core.cluster.topology.ClusterTopologyRefresh.lambda$getConnections$2(ClusterTopologyRefresh.java:228)] - [WARN] Unable to connect to 10.0.0.7:6379
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /10.0.0.7:6379
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
    at io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisClient.lambda$initializeChannelAsync0$4(AbstractRedisClient.java:329)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:511)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:504)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:483)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:424)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:121)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe$1.run(AbstractNioChannel.java:269)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask$RunnableAdapter.call(PromiseTask.java:38)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:127)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:466)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:897)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /10.0.0.7:6379
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe$1.run(AbstractNioChannel.java:267)
    ... 8 more
2019-01-14 08:16:09,935 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-9] [io.lettuce.core.cluster.topology.ClusterTopologyRefresh.lambda$getConnections$2(ClusterTopologyRefresh.java:228)] - [WARN] Unable to connect to 10.0.0.10:6379
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /10.0.0.10:6379
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
    at io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisClient.lambda$initializeChannelAsync0$4(AbstractRedisClient.java:329)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:511)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:504)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:483)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:424)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:121)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe$1.run(AbstractNioChannel.java:269)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask$RunnableAdapter.call(PromiseTask.java:38)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:127)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:466)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:897)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /10.0.0.10:6379
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe$1.run(AbstractNioChannel.java:267)
    ... 8 more
2019-01-14 08:16:09,935 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-10] [io.lettuce.core.cluster.topology.ClusterTopologyRefresh.lambda$getConnections$2(ClusterTopologyRefresh.java:228)] - [WARN] Unable to connect to 10.0.0.6:6379
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /10.0.0.6:6379
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
    at io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisClient.lambda$initializeChannelAsync0$4(AbstractRedisClient.java:329)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:511)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:504)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:483)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:424)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:121)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe$1.run(AbstractNioChannel.java:269)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask$RunnableAdapter.call(PromiseTask.java:38)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:127)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:466)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:897)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /10.0.0.6:6379
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe$1.run(AbstractNioChannel.java:267)
    ... 8 more
2019-01-14 08:16:09,935 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-11] [io.lettuce.core.cluster.topology.ClusterTopologyRefresh.lambda$getConnections$2(ClusterTopologyRefresh.java:228)] - [WARN] Unable to connect to 10.0.0.11:6379
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /10.0.0.11:6379
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
    at io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisClient.lambda$initializeChannelAsync0$4(AbstractRedisClient.java:329)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:511)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:504)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:483)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:424)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:121)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe$1.run(AbstractNioChannel.java:269)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask$RunnableAdapter.call(PromiseTask.java:38)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:127)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:466)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:897)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /10.0.0.11:6379
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe$1.run(AbstractNioChannel.java:267)
    ... 8 more
2019-01-14 08:16:09,935 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-12] [io.lettuce.core.cluster.topology.ClusterTopologyRefresh.lambda$getConnections$2(ClusterTopologyRefresh.java:228)] - [WARN] Unable to connect to 10.0.0.9:6379
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /10.0.0.9:6379
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
    at io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisClient.lambda$initializeChannelAsync0$4(AbstractRedisClient.java:329)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:511)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:504)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:483)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:424)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:121)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe$1.run(AbstractNioChannel.java:269)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask$RunnableAdapter.call(PromiseTask.java:38)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:127)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:466)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:897)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /10.0.0.9:6379
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe$1.run(AbstractNioChannel.java:267)
    ... 8 more
2019-01-14 08:16:09,935 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-5] [io.lettuce.core.cluster.topology.ClusterTopologyRefresh.lambda$getConnections$2(ClusterTopologyRefresh.java:228)] - [WARN] Unable to connect to 10.0.0.8:6379
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /10.0.0.8:6379
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
    at io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisClient.lambda$initializeChannelAsync0$4(AbstractRedisClient.java:329)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:511)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:504)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:483)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:424)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:121)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe$1.run(AbstractNioChannel.java:269)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask$RunnableAdapter.call(PromiseTask.java:38)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:127)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:466)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:897)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /10.0.0.8:6379
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe$1.run(AbstractNioChannel.java:267)
    ... 8 more
2019-01-14 08:16:15,509 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-7] [io.lettuce.core.cluster.RedisClusterClient.lambda$connect$13(RedisClusterClient.java:621)] - [WARN] io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /10.0.0.7:6379
2019-01-14 08:16:25,511 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-8] [io.lettuce.core.cluster.RedisClusterClient.lambda$connect$13(RedisClusterClient.java:621)] - [WARN] io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /10.0.0.10:6379
2019-01-14 08:16:35,518 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-9] [io.lettuce.core.cluster.RedisClusterClient.lambda$connect$13(RedisClusterClient.java:621)] - [WARN] io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /10.0.0.11:6379
2019-01-14 08:16:45,520 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-10] [io.lettuce.core.cluster.RedisClusterClient.lambda$connect$13(RedisClusterClient.java:621)] - [WARN] io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /10.0.0.9:6379
2019-01-14 08:16:55,527 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-11] [io.lettuce.core.cluster.RedisClusterClient.lambda$connect$13(RedisClusterClient.java:621)] - [WARN] io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /10.0.0.8:6379
2019-01-14 08:17:05,534 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-12] [io.lettuce.core.cluster.RedisClusterClient.lambda$connect$13(RedisClusterClient.java:621)] - [WARN] io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /10.0.0.6:6379
Jan 14, 2019 8:17:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect] with root cause
io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /10.0.0.6:6379
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe$1.run(AbstractNioChannel.java:267)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask$RunnableAdapter.call(PromiseTask.java:38)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:127)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:466)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:897)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2019-01-14 08:21:56,268 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$HouseKeeper.run(HikariPool.java:758)] - [WARN] HikariPool-1 - Retrograde clock change detected (housekeeper delta=29s293ms), soft-evicting connections from pool.
```

Looks like it directly accesses the ip address in docker swarm net not the exposed public ip address. I take a long time try to find a solution but still can't fix this. Can anyone help to figure out how to solve this problem? Thank you in advance.